# Highstock Graph not coming up properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am making multiseries highstock chart. Right now data is dummy , creating timestamp and some values in java-script . The issue is that graph is coming up but **FROM** and **TO** textbox do not show correct values . also not much info(week ,month,year) coming up in X axis range selector.

Also different graph resolutions like 1m 3m etc appears disabled.

```
 $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },....
```

please see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/Lop5d0vm/4/)

Thanks.

Comment: What values are you using on the xAxis? It should be `UTC` time in milliseconds.

Comment: Your x values should be multiplied by 1000 (http://jsfiddle.net/Lop5d0vm/5/)